# converting uppercase to lowercase in C.. (challenging one)

Tags: c

I got this code.. now the challenging part is my prof asked me to make a program which asks the user to input an uppercased word.

The problem is, she wants the program to automatically transform each inputted letter in uppercase even if the user's keyboard is not in capslock mode.. so i don't know what's really wrong with my program... anyone?? help?? i really need it.. thanks..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef char String[100];
main()
{
    char Resp;
    int l, x = 0, asc = 13;
    String s, word1;
    clrscr();
    do {
        printf("\n1st uppercased word: ");
        do {
            s[0] = getch();
            word1[x++] = s[0];
            strupr(s);
            strcat(s, "\0");
            puts(s);
        } while (s[0] != (char) asc);
        strcat(word1, "\0");

        printf("\n\n1st word in lowercase: ");
        for (l = 0; l < strlen(word1); l++)
            putchar(tolower(word1[l]));

        printf("\nDo you want to continue?[Y/N]: ");
        Resp = getche();
    } while (toupper(Resp) == 'Y');

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should tell your professor what he meant by that statement because it doesn't make any sense to say something like that. Plus your code is really hard to read with it indentation.

Comment: @thyrgle: It made sense to me --- check my answer.

Comment: @Jacob: Ohh...Ok... Still, I interpreted as you need to make a program that converts everything to uppercase. Now I want you to make sure all this works with out the user pressing capslock.

Comment: If the answer's OK, normal SO practice is to accept it.

Answer (score 11):

1. Get a letter from the user with `getch()`
2. Convert it to uppercase with `toupper()`
3. Display it with `putch()`
4. Go to 1

You may add a break point --- check if the character is the return key and exit.